# Python 3.6 Unpack a list with varying number of items

Tags: python, database, list

I am working with python lists that have varying number of items and need to build out a dynamic string (database insert statements) based on the number of items.

For example:

```
l1 = ['one','two','three']
```

The desired output is something like this. Was hoping people had more pythonic suggestions on how to approach this in the string.

```
"insert into {table} values ('{c1}', '{c2}', '{c3}')".format(table='tabName', c1=l1[0], c2=l1[1], c3=l1[2])
```

But the above obviously wont work if I now have a list with a 4th element. 
 How would you suggest that I build out the string if i have a variable number of items in my list (and thus variable number of database columns to insert into)?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Do not do this. [Don't create SQL statements by string formatting. Always use query parameters and pass the values into the `execute` call.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also, did someone tell you that `format` can only take arguments by name? If you just want to pass them positionally, just pass them positionally: `spam=[1,2,3,4]; print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(*spam))`. But that won't help you here, because the problem is that you don't know how many elements you have. For that, you want to use `join`, like `print(''.join(spam))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is [a very bad idea](https://xkcd.com/327/), as well as impossible to do the way you're attempting it.

Usually, you don't want SQL queries to be dynamic at all; you want a fixed string like this:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO tabName VALUES(?, ?, ?)'
db.execute(sql, l1)
```

Also, you usually want to add the column names, not rely on the column ordering (according to SQL standards, the order completely arbitrary, although in practice nearly every database will always use the order in which the columns were created).

In rare cases (e.g., when you're building a database administration tool), you do need dynamic SQL, but you still want to use parameters. You do this by dynamically putting parameters into the query, and then passing the list. Something like this:

```
params = ', '.join('?' for _ in l1)
sql = 'INSERT INTO {table} VALUES({params})'.format(table=tabName, params=params)
db.execute(sql, l1)
```

(But of course if `tabName` is a user-entered string, this is at least as dangerous as not using parameters.)